# Determining the most efficient number of threads to use depending on system specs

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, operating-system

How is the maximum/correct number of threads to use for an operation determined for a given system? I have an operation that could be completed with anywhere from 1 to 100 threads. I could run some tests and figure out which is the most efficient, but it seems like it would heavily depend on the user's system.

Is there a precedent for this, depending on number of cores, OS, etc?

I'm working in C#.NET, though I'm not sure that would make a difference.

Comment: You want to customize for each user system, depending on the conditions (CPU load, memory...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple rule for this, it entirely depends on what these threads are doing.  If they are burning core then the ideal number is never more than the number of cores the machine has available.  Adding more just gives the OS extra work to context-switch between them.

But if they do any I/O then they'll be blocked a lot of time, waiting for the I/O to complete.  In which case the ideal can be larger, but entirely depends on the concurrency in the I/O subsystem.

And not infrequently the ideal is just *one*.  Which is the case if the thread execution is entirely bound by a resource your machine only has one of.  Like the memory bus or the disk.

You'll have to measure.  Review the Wikipedia article for [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), pick the number where the curve flattens out.  Watch out for caching effects that make it look like your program does better than it really will do in practice.  Like running a disk-bound program over and over again and actually getting data from the file system cache instead of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect program the number of threads that you should use is the number of processors you have.

Comment: So, a perfect program has no I/O?  If it has no I/O, how do you know it's perfect?

Answer (score 0):

The Thread Pool from the .NET framework 4.5 sets by default the minimum number of threads to use depending on the number of available cores as describe here : http://www.albahari.com/threading/ in the *Optimizing the Thread Pool* section and will add or retire threads if it thinks that it will lead to a better throughput.

You can also set manually the minimum and maximum number of threads to use, in your case it would be 1 and 100.

Documentation :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx